# How can I delete a node in my linked list in C++?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, nodes, delete-operator

I've pasted my work so far here:
http://codepad.org/WhJuujRm

The concepts of linked lists boggle my mind, so I thought I'd practice. I know how to add nodes, and edit nodes, but I don't know how to remove nodes in my particular scenario.

**My Pseudo Code:**

```
previous == now - 1;
if(stdid == now->getID());
previous->setNext(now->getNext);
delete now;
return;
```

How could I implement this?

Comment: I deleted my answer because I was thinking it's a doubly-linked list. For a singly-linked list, your pseudocode looks ok to me, but I didn't look at the linked code. What is the exact problem?

Comment: I am unsure how I can implement this pseudo code in my particular scenario. I need to see my code work for my brain to click.

Comment: The `~students` destructor is already quite similar; You should just keep track of the `previous`, and when you find the student to delete, use the code as above.

Comment: I would really love a working example if at all possible.

Comment: @goatmeal perhaps you could post your cpp code on how much you've worked on, then we can point out what went wrong from there? from your codepad paste i assume you want to implement deleteStudent() that removes a student from the list?

Comment: all special cases go away if you use a sentry node, ie a dummy node that points to the first node, and that acts as a end-of-list marker. special cases regarding empty list, first node or last node go away b/c the list is never empty, and circular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mind-tease in deleting an element from a linked list is updating the pointer that brought you to the element in the first place. In your list case, that could be `top` (and/or possibly `bottom`), it could be some node's `next`. As you walk through the list hunting with a `cur` pointer, keep a `prev` pointer which you advance one step behind as you enumerate. Assuming you find the victim node (if you don't, there's nothing to do, woot!), `prev` will be in one of two states:

- It will be NULL, in which case `top` is the pointer that refers to your victim node and `top` must be updated, or...
- It will be some pointer to a node, in which case that node's `next` member needs to be updated to the reflect the victim node's `next` member value.

In *both* cases `bottom` may need updating as well. In the first case `bottom` will need to change if the list only had one node and you're deleting it. i.e. you will have an empty list when finished. Easy enough to tell, since `top` will be NULL after to detach `cur` and set `top` equal to `cur->next`. Even easier for you, since you're keeping a size member in your list container; if it was `1`, you know both `head` and `bottom`

In the second case, the *last* node may be the victim node. In that case `bottom` has to be updated to reflect the new end of the list (which is coincidentally in `prev`, and may be `NULL` if, once again, the list had only a single element. How do you tell if the victim was the last node in the list? If it's `next` member is NULL, it has to be the last node, and `bottom` *must* be updated.

So something like this, a delete function based on ID search

```
void deleteStudent(int id)
{
    student *cur = top, *prev = nullptr;
    while (cur && cur->getID() != id)
    {
        prev = cur;
        cur = cur->getNext();
    }

    // found a node?
    if (cur)
    {
        student *pNext = cur->getNext();

        // set new next pointer for prev, or new top
        if (prev)
            prev->setNext(pNext);
        else
            top = pNext;

        // update bottom if needed
        if (!pNext)
            bottom = prev;

        delete cur;
        --scnt;
    }
}
```

Other delete options and criteria I leave to you.

Best of luck.

Answer (score 1):

This should work, but I have not tested it.

There is a special case, when the first node is deleted. `previous` is set to `NULL` for the first iteration, and the `top` has to be adjusted in this case.

I didn't use `bottom`, because it's not the way I would do it. If you use `bottom`, there is a second special case, when you delete the last student. I would mark the end of the list with a `next` pointer set to `NULL`, because this eliminates this special case.

```
bool deleteStudent(int id)
{
    student* now = top;
    student* prev = NULL;
    while(now != NULL) {
        student* next = now->getNext();
        if(id == now->getID()) {
            delete now;
            if(prev) prev->setNext(next);
            else top = next;
            return true;
        }
        prev = now;
        now = next;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why **bool** in this case? Also, does this example include the special case for the first node?

Comment: 1) *true* = student found and deleted, *false* = student not found.   2) Yes, it handles the first special case (if(prev)...)

Answer (score 0):

I did not use your notation but I think you can get the point.

```
prev = NULL;
current = top;
while (current != NULL && !isfound(current)){
    prev = current;
    current = current->next;
}
// current point to the element you want to delete (if not NULL)
if(current != NULL) {
    if(previous != NULL) {
        previous->next = current->next;
    }
    else {
        top = current->next;
    }
    delete current;
}
```